# Which is faster, a MySQL `CASE` statement or a PHP `if` statement?

Tags: mysql

Which makes website more speedy retrieve data from a MySQL Database or test value inside PHP script

It is interesting for me to find answer for this question. I have 2 options for displaying data in my website.

1. To call from database like that:

   ```
   SELECT *, CASE WHEN u.sex='1' THEN 'Male' WHEN u.sex='2' THEN 'Female' END AS 'Sex' FROM users u LIMIT 30
   ```
2. test value inside PHP script

   ```
   <?php
       if ($sex==1) {$sex='Male'} else {$sex='Female'}
   ?>
   ```

Comment: `<?php echo ($sex == 1) ? 'Male' : 'Female' ?>` it's better when it's ternary

Comment: `ENUM('Male','Female')` as the column definition seems fastest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is faster. There is no need to pull data to process it again at PHP layer.

Comment: PHP was created to produce any calculations, I don't see reason why you should use database layer for some calculations not regarding to your database/data

Comment: Depends on just how much extra data the mod will take. if u.sex is an int field, that's just 2 bytes, v.s. at least 6 bytes for the string-ified versions, so that's 4 extra bytes on the wire. In the long run, the difference from this particular query is still utterly microscopic, but a blanket "do it in the database" is not always the right answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes. You should separate application logic and database retrieval. But, if you are looking to optimize the performance, you can do the calculation in database as well. It reduces the additional step of processing at PHP level.

Comment: I do agree with Marc B that such optimization is not worthwhile unless it saves you some more trips to the database.

Comment: Great thanks to all users who answered my question. I ll try 1-st one.